# Calling php script from ajax from jquery

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I'm trying to post one parameter through AJAX from jQuery and then to use certain SQL query based  on value of that parameter. Finally I want to get that response from that PHP page called through AJAX. My question is why this is not working ?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="radio-manager"]').change(function() {
        if($('#rad-400').is(':checked')){
            var id = 'reg';
        } else {
            var id = 'unreg'
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "returnCarId.php",
            data: 'id='+id,
            success: function(){
                $('h4.manager').text(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script> 

<div class="radio-line" id="radio-manager">
    <input type="radio" id="rad-400" name="radio-manager" value="No" /> Registered
    <input type="radio" id="rad-400" name="radio-manager" value="No" /> Unregistered
</div>

<h4 class="manager">Manager</h4>
```

THIS IS MY PHP PAGE  returnCarId :

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("bazait", $con);
if($_POST["id"] == "reg"){
  $sql="SELECT id from cars ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
}else{
  $sql="SELECT id from unregcars ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
}
if ($id = !mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo $id ;

mysql_close($con); 

?>
```

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: It doesn't work .. can you tell me why ? @JiriTousek

Comment: That's not a question, that's a statement. What exactly doesn't work, and what have you tried so far to make it work?

Comment: part with ajax doesn't work. even if I put on php page echo something without any other code it doesn't work. But when I remove ajax function radio buttons work perfect. But I need to call that php page. @JiriTousek

Comment: His question is why his code isn't working, and he provides the code telling us what he tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('input[name="radio-manager"]').change(function() {
        if($('#rad-400').is(':checked')){
            var id = 'reg';
        } else {
            var id = 'unreg'
        }
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url:  "returnCarId.php",
                data:{id: id},
                success: function(response){
                    $('h4.manager').text(response);
                }
            });
      });
    });
```

- You did not sent data to the server.
- you did not get response.

see baisc of [jquery ajax.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
In your php script `$id` is not defined. `mysql_*` is deprecated Use [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: But when I put just echo hello on php page ant change this method in ajax to GET it still doesn't work. @Awlad Liton

Comment: Than you so much I didn't put  function(response) I just left that empty. There was the error. @Awlad Liton

Comment: @StefanJovanic Did you tried updated code ? please remove all php script. just try: <?php echo "hello"; ?>

Comment: I'm relatively new to this if I that means to upvote your answer I already done that if it is not tell me what I have to do. @Awlad Liton

Comment: @StefanJovanic you have to accept answer if it really solve your problem.  see the link : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work